# Convert multiple array into one array in MongoDB, also remove the None values from Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Mongo DB Array Structure:

```
{

    "time" :[
           [2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z , 2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z, 2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z],
           [2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z, 2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z, 2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z],
           [2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z, 2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z, 2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z]
],
    "bar": [
           [2,5,9,8],
           [6,3,7,None],
           [7,8,None]
    ]
}
```

Expected output with One array without None values:

```
"time" :[
2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z, 
2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z, 
2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z,
2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z, 
2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z, 
2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z, 
2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z
],
    "bar": [
           2,
           5,
           9,
           6,
           3,
           7,
           8
]
}
```

I'm using Mongodb 4.2, and want to convert multiple arrays to one array, without `$unwind`. Because its reduce the performance in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- time, `$reduce` to iterate loop of time and `$concatArrays` to merge the arrays
- bar, `$reduce` to iterate loop of bar and `$concatArrays` to merge the arrays and get unique value, `$filter` to iterate loop of updated array from `$reduce` and remove `None` value from that array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      time: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$time",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      },
      bar: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$bar",
              initialValue: [],
              in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
          },
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", "None"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/om7VjfqPmCx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after this condition, I'm not getting repeated values, `bar` contains the multiple repeated values inside the array. just want to  exclude the "None"

Comment: Okay got it i looked at your expected that was unique that's why i used $setUninon.

Comment: Thanks, Its work for me. I get multiple documents. how I can make one?

document 1:
`{`
_id: abcdef,
name: "foo",
time: [1234],
doc: [1234]
`}`

document 2
`{`
_id: alexa,
name: "alexa",
time: [1234],
doc: [1234]
`}`

Expected output 
`{`
time[1234],
alexa[1234],
foo[1234]
`}`

Comment: You mean you need to combine all documents in single?  just share a playground link with your data.

Comment: [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9M3M9wNgWni). yes, I want to combine all documents into single documents.

Comment: I am not getting exactly your expected result, but i just guess this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oqp4xpFqo0n)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224315/discussion-between-bc110402922-and-turivishal).